# SQL Division - Year over Year growth rates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called y_tgtcomp made up of 17 columns.

As pictured below, each row reflects a quarterly value (4 quarters in the year).  The first column lists the quarter (image below), but this updates as time progresses with the latest quarter always at bottom (order by 1 asc).

I'm trying to select Year over Year growth rates for all columns except the first.  This requires each value to look back 4 quarters (qtr5 / qtr1 - 1) and to stop when the query looks back and finds no value / nulls. Output would be YoY growth rates for each column, order by 1 asc.

[image]

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name - I was attempting to page an image of the data, not code.  I can post an excel of the data.

Comment: @rd_nielsen I'm looking to get output that looks exactly like the image above, except it is YoY growth rates instead of the actual values.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you search for something like:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT LEFT(qrts, 2) AS year,
           COALESCE(SUM(y), 0) AS y,
           COALESCE(SUM(c1372),0) AS c1372, -- ...
    FROM y_tgtcomp
    GROUP BY LEFT(qrts,2)
)
SELECT year, y/NULLIF((LAG(y) OVER(ORDER BY year)),0) AS y_growth, ...
FROM cte
ORDER BY year ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks @lad2025.  I got the following error when trying this solution:   [57014] ERROR: Divide by zero

Comment: @ZJAY Please check now

Answer (score 0):

This should create output as you have described:

```
select
    qtrs,
    case when lag(y, 4, null) over(order by qtrs) <> 0
        then cast(y as double precision) /lag(y, 4, null) over(order by qtrs) - 1 
        else null
        end as y_yoy,
    case when lag(c5244, 4, null) over(order by qtrs) <> 0
        then c5244/lag(c5244, 4, null) over(order by qtrs) - 1 
        else null
        end as c5344_yoy
    -- Add similar case statements for other columns.
from
    y_tgtcomp
    ;
```

Consider normalizing your table so that your column headers (`y`, `c5244`, etc.) are values of a new column (`category`?).

It's not necessary for this simple use case, but if you need to do more complicated computations with quarters than simply lagging by a fixed value, you might find it useful to create a custom composite data type for quarters.  I've posted some code for this at http://splinterofthesingularity.blogspot.com/2016/11/a-year-and-quarter-data-type-for.html.